# jQuery - using selector scope as function parameter to bind events

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am applying some click events to all anchors in a grid.

I have some ajax which updates a row in the grid.

Rather than applying the events to the whole grid again, i wish to just apply to the ajax-updated row, so I pass in the scope to the bind function:

```
function bindEvents(scope)
{
 scope.find("a").click(function() { //do something });
}

function gridLoad()
{
 ..
 bindEvents($);
}

function ajax()
{
 ..
 bindEvents($(tr));
}
```

I am getting errors complaining about object doesnt support click event.

This was deffo working when the code was simply

```
$("a").click(function() { //do something });
```

also, adding a .each after the find has had no effect.

Is there best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) and you won't need to rebind the handler. It's more efficient than binding a handler for every `<a>` as well, since there's just a single event listener higher up the DOM tree.

> **Live:** Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **Delegate:** Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Just once, on document ready, like this:

```
$('#grid-id a').live('click', function ()
{
    // do something
});
```